# The confusion about windows GDI. Novice Programmer

Tags: winapi

I'm a chinese student and here is my first question I've asked in a foreign forum. 
I have written two programs, one can run normally, but the other one failed.

Here is the normal one:

```
 case WM_PAINT:
      hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;

      if(fIsTime)
          ShowTime(hdc, &st);
      else
          ShowDate(hdc, &st);

      EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
      return 0 ;
```

Here is the failed one:

```
 case WM_PAINT:
      hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
      hdcMem = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
      hBitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, cxClient, cyClient);
      ::SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

      if(fIsTime)
          ShowTime(hdcMem, &st);
      else
          ShowDate(hdcMem, &st);
      ::BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, cxClient, cyClient, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

      ::DeleteObject(hBitmap);
      ::DeleteDC(hdcMem);
      EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
      return 0 ;
```

The only difference between two codes is the `WM_Paint` code block, the latter one can not display anything. I am confused about where the error is in the latter code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your biggest problem is you have the source and destination DCs swapped around for the `BitBlt` call. The first parameter should be the destination, not the source.

Also, when you set a bitmap to a DC, you must remember the old value that is returned to you and restore it when you are finished.

Try the following:

```
  hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
  hdcMem = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
  hBitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, cxClient, cyClient);
  hbmpOld = ::SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

  if(fIsTime)
      ShowTime(hdcMem, &st);
  else
      ShowDate(hdcMem, &st);
  ::BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, cxClient, cyClient, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

  ::SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmpOld);
  ::DeleteObject(hBitmap);
  ::DeleteDC(hdcMem);
  EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
  return 0 ;
```

Comment: oh, I reversed destination and source.. Thank you very much.